# Automatic trailing slash redirect leaks internal IP in the Location header

Tags: redirect, nginx

When doing `curl -ILk http://192.168.0.4/app` the Location header of the 301 redirect is `http://my-srv.local/app/` which is a server-local address. I've put `server_name_in_redirect on` everywhere to get rid of it, but the result is the same.

Config:

```
server {
    server_name my-nginx;
    server_name_in_redirect on;
    set $endpoint http://my-srv.local;
    location / {
        server_name_in_redirect  on;
        proxy_pass               $endpoint;
    }
}
```

Note: the nginx version that I'm using doesn't have `absolute_redirect` yet.

Reference: [Information leak with automatic trailing slash redirect](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/523)

How to make it point to the correct URL or prevent the leak at least?

Comment: `nginx` is not generating the redirect, the endpoint is. You could try adding one of more [`proxy_redirect` statements](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_redirect) to change the `Location` header.

Comment: @RichardSmith, looks like `proxy_redirect $endpoint http://$host;` does the right thing. Is that what you propose?

Comment: If you cannot change endpoint it may be your only other solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it's the `my-srv.local` who generates that response (that is pretty reasonable). With the nginx 1.11.8+ it will probably generate relative redirects. In the meantime, the possible fix is to overwrite that redirect:

```
server {
    server_name my-nginx;
    set $endpoint http://my-srv.local;
    location / {
        proxy_pass               $endpoint;
        proxy_redirect           $endpoint http://$host;
    }
}
```